# How do I find a day of the week?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

**What is the name of the last day of the month of April, 2008?**

How do I do this? This isn't from a table.
Do I use TO_CHAR, SYSDATE, what?

```
SQL> select to_char(30-4-2008,'day') WEEKDAY from dual;

SQL> select to_char(to_date('03/30/2008','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Dy')
  2  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_char` with the format mask of `fmDay` (the leading `fm` eliminates the trailing whitespace).

```
  1* select to_char( date '2008-04-30', 'fmDay' ) from dual
SQL> /

TO_CHAR(D
---------
Wednesday
```

This will return the name of the day in the current session's NLS settings (i.e. `Wednesday` if the session is using English, something else if the NLS settings are different).  You can pass additional parameters to `to_char` if you want to force the name of the day to be in English regardless of the session's NLS settings.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the fmDAY elsewhere, never saw it before today, wasnt sure it was needed.